# Convert strings to ids as MySQL composite key

Tags: php, mysql, database-performance

I send a lot of request during a second to the database in a following pattern:

```
name1 | name2 | time
aaa     bbb     5
aaa     bbb     2
ccc     ddd     3
```

`name1-name2` is a composite key, there are maybe 10 combinations of those, and more than a million records in a table.

Now, because these are strings, it's really slow to select something from that. I've been thinking about converting this composite key to some integer to speed it up, and make it one column instead of two.

Will this really speed up my database?

How can I convert this composite key to achieve this?

Comment: Why would strings be slower than integers?

Comment: Aren't ids generally faster than strings as keys?

Comment: Please show the complete definition of the table -- including all keys and indexes -- and the queries you're using to insert and retrieve rows. Also, please be more specific about your performance problem than "really slow."

Comment: Are your `name1` and `name2` columns properly indexed?

Comment: `CREATE TABLE 'times'(name1 varchar(15), name2 varchar(15), time int, PRIMARY KEY(name1, name))`

Comment: `SELECT AVG(time) FROM times WHERE name1 = 'aaa' AND name2 = 'bbb';`

Comment: This question (with a LOT more detail) probably belongs on http://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Really slow means relatively slower to ids.

Comment: A numeric key will be more efficient (less space in the index file, fewer branches in the B-tree). But if your input is names, how will you translate that to the numeric key to look up the rows?